# Data Transfer IN for EC2 Instances in different account but same region

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, linux-networking

Consider this scenario
Two EC2 Instances in two **DIFFERENT** accounts in **us-east-1** communicate over the **Public IP** (The two accounts are **not** linked and there is **no** VPC-peering or anything)

**EC2 A** -----[***us-east-1*** over ***public*** IP]-----> ***EC2 B***

It is *very clear* for me that the **EC2 A** will pay for Data Transfer **OUT**

*BUT*

1) How much is **EC2 A** charged for Data Transfer **OUT** ?

- (a) $0.090/GB - Data Transfer OUT From ***Amazon EC2 To Internet***
- (b) $0.010/GB - Data Transfer OUT From ***Amazon EC2 To Amazon EC2*** in the *same* AWS Region Using a *public or Elastic* IPv4 address

2) How much is **EC2 B** charged for Data Transfer **IN** ?

- (a) $0,000/GB - Data Transfer IN To ***Amazon EC2 From Internet***
- (b) $0,010/GB - Data Transfer IN To ***Amazon EC2 From Amazon EC2*** in the *same* AWS Region Using a *public or Elastic* IPv4 address

I already contacted the support and got different answers, so I'm confused and hope that someone from AWS or community could solve this confusion.

Best Regards

Comment: In https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/, see the "Using an IPv6 address from a different VPC" and "Using a public or Elastic IPv4 address" bits. Looks like $0.010/GB to me.

Comment: @ceejayoz you mean EC2 A and EC2 B pays $0.010/GB each ?

Comment: It appears that way to me, yes.